# Solving the derivative for a variable star's period and radius

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics, mathematical-astronomy

I am trying to solve for $R$ as this is the radius of a RR Lyrae type of variable star from the formula: $$P^{-1}\frac{dP}{dT}=1.5R^{-1} \frac{dP}{dT}$$
$P$ is the star's brightness variability period and of course here we are to be taking the derivative of the period with respect to time.

Here are my questions: The period IS a rate of change, so isn't the value I get from my data for the period the derivative already?  As such could I just replace the $P^{-1}\frac{dP}{dT}$ with that value?  But then how do I take the derivative of the $R^{-1}\frac{dP}{dT}$?  Surely I don't just replace this with the period value as well; that would result in turning this into a simple algebraic equation.  Do I need to take an integral to solve for $R$, and if so can someone show me how that is done in this instance?  I am using a spreadsheet to sort my data and eventually determine the period of several of these types of stars, so is there a different value I need to put in for $P$ and then let $T$ be the overall length of time for imaging (for instance, suppose I imaged a star for $2$ weeks; would $T$ be $14$ days)?

Thanks to all who are working on this!
-Melanie and Dave

Comment: What's $T$, `temperature` or `time`?

Comment: T is time, the unit I believe is in days

Comment: I presume there's a typo in your equation: shouldn't it be $dR/dT$ on the right hand side?

Answer (score 1):

Your equation (I corrected a typo)
$$P^{-1}\frac{dP}{dT}=1.5R^{-1} \frac{dR}{dT}$$
can be rewritten as
$$\frac{d}{dT}\ln P=\frac{d}{dT}(1.5\ln R),$$
that is:
$$\ln P=\ln R^{1.5}+\text{constant},$$
and finally:
$$P=k\cdot R^{1.5},$$
where $k$ is a constant, to be determined from initial conditions.